# Showing $A_{\infty}$ is an event

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,A,P)$ a probability space and consider $A_{n}$ a sequence of events. I want to show that $A_{\infty}=\cap_{n} \cup_{k\geq n}A_{k}$ is an event (i.e. the event that infinitely many $A_{n}$ occur), so I want to show that $A_{\infty}$ is a measurable set, but I don't see how.

Comment: $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions and intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just note that $\cup_{k\ge n} A_k$ is an event by countable unions, and then call these events $B_n$. Then you have

$$\bigcap_n B_n=A_\infty$$

is an event because it is a countable intersection of events.